# scribe log analysis

Tags: php, logging, hadoop, hbase, scribe

I have decided to use scribe to log all the error and request details in my site for analysis.
How can I use the scribe log data to analyze the data.  Is there any tool for this or scribe server programs?
I am using PHP as my scripting language

Answer (score 1):

People usually use the Hadoop framework to process data coming out of scribe. You can use PHP to script map/reduce steps...

However, unless you have a lot of data, this is probably going to be a lot of work for a small benefit:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/

Good luck with that !